# How many conjugacy classes are in this collection?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a subspace of $M(n,\mathbb{R})$, such that, for every $A\in V$, $A$ only has real eigenvalues. (i.e. $\forall \lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, if $\operatorname{det}(\lambda I_n-A)=0$, then $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.)

Define: $\mathscr{E}:=\{V\ |\ \ V \text{satisfies the above condition.}\}$, then $(\mathscr{E},\subseteq)$ is a partially ordered set.

Define $\mathscr{F}$ to be the collection of all maximal elements in $\mathscr{E}$. Suppose $V_1, V_2\in\mathscr{F}$, we say $V_1, V_2$ are conjugate if $\exists P\in\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ such that $V_1=PV_2P^{-1}$. (i.e. $V_1=\{PAP^{-1} | A\in V_2\}$.)

Question1: How many conjugacy classes are in $\mathscr{F}$?

Qusetion2: every subspace in $\mathscr{F}$ has real dimension $\binom{n+1}{2}$?

My thinking: easy to see, {upper triangular matrices}, {lower triangular matrices}, {symmetric matrices} are in $\mathscr{F}$. Via matrix$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & ... & 0 & 1 \\
0 & ... & 1 & 0 \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
1 & 0 & ... & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $, we know that {lowers} and {uppers} are conjugate. But {Symmetric} and {uppers} are not conjugate, because {uppers} is closed under Lie branket, but {Symmetric} is not. So, there are at least 2 conjugate classes in $\mathscr{F}$.